# BeanManager method getReference() is not available during application initialization

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-10, jboss-weld

I am trying to deploy a war file into Wildfly 10.0.0.Final, the deployment fails with the following error :

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"management-app.war\\\".WeldStartService\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"management-app.war\\\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001332: BeanManager method getReference() is not available during application initialization
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.checkContainerState(BeanManagerProxy.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:84)
    at morpho.mcp.adapter.cdi.AdapterExtension.getAdapterDefinition(AdapterExtension.java:159)
    at morpho.mcp.adapter.cdi.AdapterExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(AdapterExtension.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
\"}}"
```

Assuming that the war was working fine for JBoss AS7. What could be the possible root cause for such behavior ?

It seems that a WAR which is not a bean archive is missing the org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService dependency. But how can this issue be resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can this issue be resolved ?

Do not use `BeanManager.getReference` before `AfterDeploymentValidation`. Refactor your code accordingly. The reason is - `getReference` might give you incomplete results. At that point, the bootstrap is not yet done and `getReference` method might fail to retrieve a reference as there might not be one at a given time (although it would be there later on).

As for *how to workaround this*:

Use Weld [`non-portable mode`](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_non_portable_mode_during_application_initialization) although that might have more undesirable effects. You should firstly try to refactor the code before falling back to this configuration.